# How to resolve freezes when pressing caps lock on external keyboard

Tags: keyboard, usb

I've been trying to diagnose a problem with my Logitech K120 keyboard paired with a Macbook Pro 15" (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013) where occasionally, pressing the caps lock would cause that keyboard to completely stop responding for a few seconds. I'd previously used this keyboard with a Windows PC, and found no issues.

I've tried the following:

1. Setting the modifier key to do nothing and then setting it back (per [this Superuser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/317900/eliminate-macbook-capslock-delay/1224132))
2. Installing Karabiner Elements (from the [same Superuser thread](https://superuser.com/a/1224132/103066). This actually makes it worse, in that when the keyboard freezes the computer, it never unfreezes until I kill Karabiner

Has anyone encountered this before? I might just try replacing the keyboard soon, but I was hoping there'd be a software or configuration fix that would work.

Comment: *where occasionally, pressing the caps...*. So, it’s intermittent?  This is next to impossible to diagnose without further context.  The first diagnostic procedure I would try is booting into Safe Mode and seeing if the problem persists. But if it’s intermittent, you may not see results right away.

Answer (score 2):

This has happened to me on two different Macs with 3 different bluetooth keyboards. Two Apple keyboards and one Logitech. The symptom is always the same, intermittently the keyboard will freeze for about 5 seconds after hitting the caps lock key.

Restarting the computer will often resolve the issue for a short time but an SMC reset normally resolves the issue more long term.

I have had this experience over the last 5 years and have found documentation of others having the exact same issue for over a decade. It's obviously a larger underlying issue and I'm not sure why it persists.

Comment: Also here in the "me too" party. Magic keyboard freezes all input for a few seconds after hitting caps lock. Magic trackpad freezes too while that freeze is active.

Comment: I swapped the logic board for a Mac to upgrade the RAM and the issue seems to have gone away. I have to assume that it's due to some logic board (or connection) issue